# How to use Spring's @ManagedOperation with an Enum parameter?

Tags: java, spring, enums, jmx, jconsole

I am trying to use the`org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedOperation` annotation on a method that takes an enum as a parameter.

However when I access said Application via Jconsole I get:
"Error setting Operation panel..."

Is this not possible? Why won't it take a String at least as input for the enum?

i.e.

```
@ManagedOperation
public void doStuff(String id, MyEnum myEnum) {
...
}
```